# How do you add validation to Ember.Textfield value binding by limiting character types?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I have an input field for a name, as seen below:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="segment_name" type="text" placeholder="Give your new segment a name" id="segment_name" class="input-xlarge" required="required"}}
```

I'd like to validate the characters used in the name (ie: not allowing # character in segment_name field), and I have this to show for it:

```
$('#segment_name').bind('keypress', function(e) {
            console.log( e.which );
            if($('#segment_name').val().length == 0){
                var k = e.which;
                var ok = k >= 65 && k <= 90 || // A-Z
                    k >= 97 && k <= 122 || // a-z
                    k >= 48 && k <= 57; // 0-9

                if (!ok){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
```

See this JS Fiddle for a similar example: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D4dcg/)

I haven't had any luck with the code above validating my characters as I type in the TextField binding. I was struggling to see where to put the code above in my Ember app? Do I put it in the helpers or in the controller?

Any workarounds/hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to `keyDown`, `keyUp` and `keyPress` events from the `View` class as shown [**here**](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/)

Comment: I will try implementing that as well. Do you have any other suggestions to solve this issue?